# How to open local text file with JavaFX WebView

Tags: java, webview, javafx-2

Is that possible to open local text file with JavaFX WebView ? I have tried the following code but it was not working. How can I enable this?

```java
WebView wv = new WebView();
wv.getEngine().setCreatePopupHandler(new Callback<PopupFeatures, WebEngine>() {

    @Override
    public WebEngine call(PopupFeatures p) {
        Stage stage = new Stage(StageStyle.UTILITY);
        WebView wv2 = new WebView();
        stage.setScene(new Scene(wv2));
        stage.show();
        return wv2.getEngine();
    }
});

wv.getEngine().loadContent("<a href="file:///C:\Users\Dev\infor.txt">Open File</a>");

StackPane root = new StackPane();
root.getChildren().add(wv);

Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
primaryStage.setScene(scene);
primaryStage.show();
```

Comment: Did you try `wv.getEngine().load("file:///C:\\Users\\Dev\\infor.txt");`

Comment: Hi Abishek. I have tried it but failed.Thanks.

Comment: What exactly is not working? Do you receive an exception or error message? What happens when you click on the link? "it was not working" does not provide enough information on what the problem is.

Comment: Hi Lolo, That mean when I click the link, it will happen nothing. But when I set target='_blank' then it will open empty popup. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can open a local text file with a JavaFX WebView.

*Sample app:*

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class WebViewWithLocalText extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws MalformedURLException {
        String location =
                new File(
                        System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separator + "test.txt"
                ).toURI().toURL().toExternalForm();

        System.out.println(location);

        WebView webView = new WebView();
        webView.getEngine().load(location);

        // use loadContent instead of load if you want a link to a file.
        // webView.getEngine().loadContent(
        //     "<a href=\"" + location + "\">Open File</a>"
        // );

        Scene scene = new Scene(webView);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Place a text file at the location reported by System.out when you run the program.

*Sample output:*

[image: output]

*Some errors in your supplied code:*

1. You don't escape quotes.
2. You don't supply a valid file URI, you supply windows path prefixed by a file protocol.
3. You hardcode a path and drive specifier, which is likely not a portable solution between systems.

I don't have a windows machine to test, but perhaps something like this would work for your absolute path.

```
wv.getEngine().loadContent("<a href=\"file:///C:/Users/Dev/infor.txt\">Open File</a>");
```

See also:

- [File URIs in Windows](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2006/12/06/file-uris-in-windows.aspx).

Comment: Hi Jewelsea, Many thanks for your great answer. Yes it can make enable way you have mention. Actually in my case I can not define files explicitly. Because I have to display with WebView, some text value query from the data base. Therefore with that text content it's bit hard to identify those local files individually (I can only set that text value to WebView as webView.getEngine().loadContent(textValue)). Can you please suggest any solution for this issue. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Your original question was about loading a local text file into a WebView.  Your follow-up question (loading a string from memory into a WebView), is different, so you should ask it in a new question.   As a hint, loadContent is for loading a data from memory, it says so in its javadoc.  Use the [loadContent variant which allows you to specify a text mime-type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/web/WebEngine.html#loadContent-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-)  so that the data isn't treated as HTML.  The text mime type is `text/plain`.